# How to support landscape mode in uiwebview video tag?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, uiwebview

I am loading a mp4 video file from a url using the video tag into a uiwebview:

```
<body style=\"margin:0\"><video src=\"%@\" width=\"285\" height=\"203\" 
poster=\"%@\" autoplay=\"autoplay\" controls=\"controls\"></video></body>
```

However the video plays only in portait mode using the QuickTime player. How can i make the video play in landscape too?

I cannot override the function to support orientation as my application is portrait mode based, but since video starts in full screen mode, I want it to support both orientations.

Youtube player supports both orientations though. So are there any options to get both orientations working?

Answer (score 0):

It's a bit of a hack, but you could try something like this:

[Autorotating video played from HTML5 <video> in UIWebView](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5327346/autorotating-video-played-from-html5-video-in-uiwebview/5741432#5741432)