# How to make landscape mode for playing youtube video in IOs7?

Tags: ios, iphone, ipad, uiwebview, uiinterfaceorientation

I had an iPhone Tabbar application in which I had a UIWebView,to which i am pushing from a UITableViewController.
some times it may be a link for an youtube video. My application is supporting Portrait mode only although the application.
But when this youtube video is playing i need to force the app in to landscape mode when finishing to portrait.
Basically i need to play the youtube videos in landscape mode only. I had come across so many similar questions but all are bellow iOS 5. Can anybody help me on this?

I tried this

> [Autorotating video played from HTML5 <video> in UIWebView](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5327346/autorotating-video-played-from-html5-video-in-uiwebview/5741432#5741432)  but not worked

Comment: Why forcing it? Some videos suited for portrait mode and will look bad in force landscape mode. Don't waste your time for this.

Comment: @TussLászló my client needs when the video is playing in a Uiwebview it needs to be in landscape